# Only half of the navigation bar is being displayed for a UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I've created a very simple app with a UINavigationController as the root controller but when I run it only half (the left hand side) of the navigation bar is displayed. Why is this? It seems strange - if I've done something wrong you'd think it wouldn't display at all, but instead its exactly half!

The controller looks like this:

> ```
> @interface RootController : UINavigationController { 
>     UIWebView*  webView;
>     NSMutableString       *htmlString;
> }
> ```

With corresponding @property declarations and @synthesize.

I'm not using any .nibs for the view controller/view. The app delegate is:

> ```
> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
> {
>     RootController* theRVC = [[RootController alloc] init];
>     self.window.rootViewController = theRVC;
>     [theRVC release];
>     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
>     return YES;
> }
> ```

And the controller has the following relevant code:

> ```
> - (void)loadView
> {
>     webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
>     self.view = webView;
>     [webView release];
> }
>
> - (void)viewDidLoad
> {
>     [super viewDidLoad];
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't derive from `UINavigationController`.

Instead, derive your `RootController` class from UIViewController.
Then, in the application delegate you init a UINavigationController passing in the RootController, and set it as the windows rootViewController.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    RootController* theRVC = [[RootController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:theRVC];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [theRVC release];
    [navController release];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it always incorrect to derive from UINavigationController?

Comment: It is rare to need to derive from UINavigationController.  If you were to, it would be to customise some aspect of the navigation controller itself, not to define the content view controller.